# Convert column dateformat inline with sql query

Tags: android, sqlite, date-format, julian-date

I have stored date in a column of android sqlite database in YYYY/MM/DD format . Now I want to use julianday function in sql query to select special rows of database however julianday uses date in YYYY-MM-DD format . How can I convert date format inline with sql query?

Please rewrite this sample query which "startdate" and "enddate" are stored in YYYY/MM/DD format not YYYY-MM-DD:

```
select * from events where julianday(enddate)-julianday(startdate)>1200
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL query accepts inline replace:

```
select * from events where julianday(replace(enddate,'/','-'))-julianday(replace(startdate,'/','-'))>1200
```

for more complex conversion use prepared SQL **[convert()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)** function